# React Video plays locally on web, but does not play on mobile devices after deployment to Heroku

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-development-server

I've also added a web.config file, but it is still not working.

This is how the web.config looks

```html
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This is my code for the video in the render body for react

```js
<ReactPlayer
    className="video-frame"
    url="../images/video.mp4"
    muted
    playing={true}
    autoPlay={true}
    width='auto'               
    loop={true}/>
```

Comment: Can you provide Minimum Reproducible Example or console Error you are getting?

Comment: Hi it works now -- but the video does not play on mobile devices.

Comment: Does it work on a laptop?

Comment: It works on laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Video does not play on mobile because autoplay is disabled on mobile web browsers.
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes